# What is the appropriate action to take, if any, if a fielder is too close for her/his own safety?

Tags: cricket, etiquette

In amateur cricket, as a batsman, if you have only one planned shot, a hard one, and you know you are quite able to execute it, but a fielder, without obvious protection (e.g., a helmet), creeps up on you to say 4 yards, in front of you, what is the right thing to do?

Should you warn her/him? Should you inform the umpires? Should you refuse to bat? What?

Comment: Is cricket exclusively played by men?

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra No. But the creeping-up-types are always men (in my experience). And, although not sure, I think the term "batsman" is unisex.

Comment: I was referring to _Should you warn him?_ and _his_ in the title.

Comment: A couple of fierce shots whistling past his ear is likely to be enough to send him back to the outfield. When you say "creeps up", do you mean the fielder moves before the bowler starts his/her run up, or afterwards?

Comment: @Spinner Yes, but what if the first shot hits her/him between the ears? :) I meant "before".

Comment: @Gugg I doubt he has much between them if he's fielding there without a helmet. And that makes your point even more emphatically; the only regret you should have is that you've missed out on four runs!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In junior cricket, the (adult) coaches and umpires have a responsibility to ensure player safety and should (and in my experience typically do) intervene to prevent players putting themselves in unnecessary danger in this fashion. In Australia at least, over the last 5-10 years the wearing of protective equipment by junior players has become universal due to an increased desire for player safety.

On the other hand, if it is senior cricket then players can do as they wish. If you are batting and you feel that you are endangering a fielder, remember *that is what they want you to think.* The whole point of fielding so close is not to actually take a catch ( you don't need to be so close to do so) but to toy with the batter's mind. If the position of the fielder is worrying you, then the fielder is doing their job. Focus on your own job and let the fielder worry about their safety. Remember that the bowler is sprinting in and putting all their might into bowling a hard object as hard as possible at your head. The bowler doesn't want to hurt you as such, but your safety is none of their concern. You should have the same attitude about fielders.

Comment: In some districts in Australia, there is a requirement even in senior cricket for fielders to wear a helmet when fielding within 10 metres of the bat in front of the wicket.

Comment: Umpires are also supposed to bear player safety in mind, and can & should mention to players that they're in an unsafe position. They can't force the player to move though. There is also the question of encroaching on the pitch, which fielders cannot do, and of shadows distracting the batsman - the fielder is required to remain still in this case.